# Basic framework for private album using keys?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to implement a private album feature on my site and I'm looking for some basic framework.  Are there any scripts available or frameworks to start with?

I've looked through Google but can't seem to find anything useful.

Basically all I want to do is let a user request access to another users private photo album.  If the second user agrees he can generate a private key that will allow the first user to access the private album.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use something like http://gallery.menalto.com/ with a [module](http://codex.gallery2.org/Gallery2%3aModules).

For example the [hidden module](http://codex.gallery2.org/Gallery2%3aModules%3ahidden) will hide an album from overview. So the album can only be access with the knowledge of the url. There is also the [password module](http://codex.gallery2.org/Gallery2%3aModules%3apassword). with this module you can set a password to a single album.